# libparted determine used sector

Tags: c++, c, qt

I try to determine the sectors used in the partition. But libparted doesn't appear support ntfs/ext4 for resizing parition, in my code i just need to know how much sector is used.

Error code: "Error: resizing ntfs file systems is not supported"

```
SLPartition::SLPartition(PedPartition *partition, SLDrive *drive) :
    _pedPartition(0),
    _drive(0),
    _mountInfo(QString()),
    _path(QString()),
    _name(QString()),
    _start(0),
    _end(0),
    _size(0),
    _sector(0)
{
    if(partition)
    {
        this->_pedPartition = partition;
        this->_drive        = drive;
        this->_path         = ped_partition_get_path(partition);
        this->_name         = QString::number(partition->num);
        this->_start        = partition->geom.start;
        this->_end          = partition->geom.end;
        this->_sector       = partition->geom.length;
        this->_size         = partition->geom.length / 2;


        qint64 usedSector = -1;

        PedFileSystem *pedFileSystem = ped_file_system_open(&partition->geom);

        if(pedFileSystem)
        {
            if(PedConstraint* pedConstraint = ped_file_system_get_resize_constraint(pedFileSystem))
            {
                usedSector = pedConstraint->min_size;
                ped_constraint_destroy(pedConstraint);
            }

            ped_file_system_close(pedFileSystem);
        }

        qDebug() << usedSector;

        // TODO MountInfo
    }
}
```

Is there an alternative solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to shell out to `sfdisk` which has machine parseable output.